# Errores en practica de POO para hacer una petición a la BBDD $=$this->conexion_db->query

Tags: php, mysql, poo, get, mysqldb

Hola y muy buenos dias a todos, viendo una clase en la que me explican a cerca de POO para hacer una conexión a una tabla de mysql

(Utilizo XAMPP y reciclando un excel para crear una tabla con supuestos varios a los que poder consultar. De ahi que existan acentos en los campos.)

en la que siguiendo paso a paso lo que hace el profe, me da los siguientes errores:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cursophp\mysql\ACCESO A LA BBDD EN POO\devuelvealumno.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cursophp\mysql\ACCESO A LA BBDD EN POO\html.php(4): DevuelveAlumnos->get_alumnos() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cursophp\mysql\ACCESO A LA BBDD EN POO\devuelvealumno.php on line 13

quiero saber en que me he equivocado, realmente desconozco por que no ejecuta la query, y soy muy principiante por ahora, estaría eternamente agradecido, aquí va mi código:

#1 config.php

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

define('DB_USUARIO', 'root');

define('DB_CONTRA', '');

define('DB_NOMBRE', 'prueba_bdd');

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

?>
```

#2 conexion.php

```
<?php

require ("config.php");

class Conexion {


    protected $conexion_db;

    public function Conexion(){

      $this->conexion_db=new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);

        if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno) {


            echo "Fallo al conectar con MYSQL: " . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;

            return;
        }

        $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);
    }
}
?>
```

#3 devuelvealumno.php

```
<?php
require "conexion.php";

class DevuelveAlumnos extends Conexion{

    public function DevuelveAlumnos(){

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_alumnos(){

        $resultado=$this->conexion_db->query('SELECT * FROM alumnos_matriculados');

        $alumnos=$resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        return $alumnos;
    }
}


?>
```

#4 html.php

```
<?php
   require "./devuelvealumno.php";
   $alumnos=new DevuelveAlumnos();
   $array_alumnos=$alumnos->get_alumnos();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>devuelve alumnos</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php

    foreach ($array_alumnos as $elemento){

    echo "<table><tr><td>";
    echo $elemento['Numero'] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elemento['DNI'] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elemento['Alumno'] . "</td><td>";
    echo $elemento['Email'] . "</td><td></tr></table>";

    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";



}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe a que `$conexion_db` no está definido cuando lo usas.

En PHP el constructor de clases no es el mismo nombre de la clase (típico en C++). En este lenguaje existe un método llamado [__construct()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php). Es ahí donde deberías crear la instancia.

Tenés que cambiar esta línea:

```
public function Conexion(){
```

Por esta:

```
public function __construct() {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!!! Si funcionó la instancia cuando coloque ____construct() {